# C++ function: Number of memory access

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, profiling

I want to find out the number of memory accesses resulted due to a certain function. For this purpose , I am making use of pintool. In pintool, I made use of pinatrace but that generates a huge file (file size > 534 MB) with all the reads and writes of the whole program . But I want to find it out for one particular function. I have still not find any example doing that. Please help me in this regard or provide me any useful link.

P.S : I am compiling my c++ program on Linux.

Comment: I'm not familiar with pintool's output format, but I'm almost sure you can give some switches which result in an output that you can parse using standard tools like grep, awk, etc.
If you give us a sample output, it might help.

Comment: Use nm(1) to get the starting address of your function.  Maybe disassemble the function to get its size.

Comment: @brianbeuning Can you please elaborate? where to use nm(1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cachegrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html), which is part of Valgrind, measures (or rather, simulates) the number of cache accesses as well as cache misses (i.e. accesses to actual RAM). Find an overview [here](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html#cg-manual.overview).

It can output an annotated version of your code, with counts of cache accesses and cache misses line by line in [this format](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html#cg-manual.line-by-line) as well.

Valgrind is included in package managers for popular OS and easy to install.

Here is an example:

```
#include <random>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> vec;

  // Seed with a real random value, if available
  std::random_device rd;
  std::default_random_engine eng(rd());
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(1,10000);

  for (std::size_t i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; ++i)
    vec.push_back(dist(eng));

  for (auto &num : vec)
    num *= 3;

  return 0;
}
```

1. Compile (make sure you use the -g option)

   ```
   g++ -std=c++11 -W -Wall -g -o test test.cpp
   ```
2. Run valgrind in cachegrind mode

   ```
   valgrind --tool=cachegrind ./test
   ```
3. Run the cg_annotate tool:

   ```
   cg_annotate ./cachegrind.out.2543 /absolute/path/test.cpp
   ```

This produces:

```
==2438== Cachegrind, a cache and branch-prediction profiler
==2438== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Nicholas Nethercote et al.
==2438== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2438== Command: ./test
==2438== 
--2438-- warning: L3 cache found, using its data for the L2 simulation.
==2438== 
==2438== I   refs:      1,686,675
==2438== I1  misses:        1,160
==2438== LLi misses:        1,095
==2438== I1  miss rate:      0.06%
==2438== LLi miss rate:      0.06%
==2438== 
==2438== D   refs:        676,987  (458,995 rd   + 217,992 wr)
==2438== D1  misses:       12,616  ( 11,023 rd   +   1,593 wr)
==2438== LLd misses:        6,338  (  5,272 rd   +   1,066 wr)
==2438== D1  miss rate:       1.8% (    2.4%     +     0.7%  )
==2438== LLd miss rate:       0.9% (    1.1%     +     0.4%  )
==2438== 
==2438== LL refs:          13,776  ( 12,183 rd   +   1,593 wr)
==2438== LL misses:         7,433  (  6,367 rd   +   1,066 wr)
==2438== LL miss rate:        0.3% (    0.2%     +     0.4%  )
```

**Note 1**: Cachegrind *simulates* cache behavior, so its output may not be entirely accurate. In particular, the simulation only takes into account the process you are profiling; it ignores OS/Kernel activities and other processes.

**Note 2**: Cachegrind, too, may generate a large intermediary file. So if your issue is the space requirement, Cachegrind may not be a good solution. But if your issue is merely the format and readability of the output, it will help, because the cg_annotate generates easy-to-read output.

Comment: I used cachegrind and also used -g while compiling and linking but still the function in which I was interested, its stats are not there. Even that function name is not present.

Comment: Perhaps the function was inlined. In that case you'd still get annotations for the calls *inside* the function.

Answer (score 0):

pinatrace is just an example meant for tracing every instruction with mem operands. 
When it calls (for e.g.) -

```
// Print a memory read record
VOID RecordMemRead(VOID * ip, VOID * addr)
{
    fprintf(trace,"%p: R %p\n", ip, addr);
}
```

It gets passed an `IARG_INST_PTR` which is the IP (instruction pointer) of the captured instruction. If you know the range of virtual addresses where your function resides you can just add a check inside and return without printing anything if you're not in that range.

Comment: Is there any other easy way to achieve this goal (mentioned in my question)?

Comment: depends on what exactly you have in you binary file - if you don't have debug info then the only way to identify this function is using its addresses